# Python: remove duplicates from a multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, numpy, duplicates

In Python `numpy.unique` can remove all duplicates from a 1D array, very efficiently.

1) How about to remove duplicate rows or columns in a **2D array**?

2) How about for **nD arrays**?

Comment: can you illustrate what you are trying to achieve with a simple example.

Comment: @root One case we may use to remove duplicate points (2D or 3D) from a point cloud.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If possible I would use pandas.

```
In [1]: from pandas import *

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: a = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 3], [1, 1], [5, 4], [2, 3]])

In [4]: DataFrame(a).drop_duplicates().values
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [5, 4]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: `pandas` is not installed yet. Can you give some benchmarks. BTW, input `array` to be `float`s not integers. Try for over 10k points.

Comment: Well having `pandas` installed now, its performance is outstanding: for 30k points (3D) with duplicates 10k total 40k, only 0.2s. wow!

Answer (score 1):

The following is another approach which performs much better than `for` loop. 2s for 10k+100 duplicates.

```
def tuples(A):
    try: return tuple(tuples(a) for a in A)
    except TypeError: return A

b = set(tuples(a))
```

The idea inspired by *Waleed Khan*'s first part. 
So no need for any additional package that is may have further applications.
It is also super Pythonic, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package solves this problem for the n-dimensional case. (disclaimer: I am its author). Infact, solving this problem was the motivation for starting this package; but it has grown to include a lot of related functionality.

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
a = np.random.randint(0, 2, (3, 3, 3))
print(npi.unique(a))
print(npi.unique(a, axis=1))
print(npi.unique(a, axis=2))
```