# How to group element in list with python 2.7

Tags: python, list

I have car positions (X,Y) at differents dates :

```
input =[
         [21/01/2017,"carA",2053005.39445,701577.391706],
         [22/01/2017,"carA",2053005.39445,701577.391706],
         [23/01/2017,"carA",2053005.39445,701577.391706],
         [24/01/2017,"carA",2052759.49583,701843.214278],
         [25/01/2017,"carA",2052759.49583,701843.214278]
       ]
```

The first three lines have the same positions and the last two lines have the same position too. I would like store the start date and the end date in a new list like this:

```
output=[
        [21/01/2017,23/01/2017,"carA",2053005.39445,701577.391706],
        [24/01/2017,25/01/2017,"carA",2052759.49583,701843.214278]
       ]
```

Comment: Have a look at `itertools.groupby`

Comment: @depperm it's not exactly what i'm trying to do. I try to group the dates  by  the cars positions (X,Y) and store in other list the start date , the end date and cars positions. So, I have a new element (end date) per output line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: remove duplicates from a multi-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089453/python-remove-duplicates-from-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 1):

As already proposed `itertools.groupby` can be used. But your input has to be (correctly) sorted because it only groups consecutive items:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

output = []
for key, group in groupby(input, key=itemgetter(2, 3)):
    group = list(group)
    output.append([group[0][0], group[-1][0]] + group[0][1:])

output
# [['21/01/2017', '23/01/2017', 'carA', 2053005.39445, 701577.391706],
#  ['24/01/2017', '25/01/2017', 'carA', 2052759.49583, 701843.214278]]
```

Another tip: `input` is a builtin-function, having a variable with the same name is usually not recommended!

---

Note that such lists are generally hard to process later. You could instead store them as `collections.namedtuple` to give them more context.